# Retrieved saved file from SQL database when editing a form in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, file-upload

I have  a form where a user can capture information about an invoice. As part of that form the user can upload and save a pdf file copy of that invoice into the database.

I am using **the same form** to save a new invoice and to edit already captured invoices.

The problem I have is that when a user edits an already existing invoice and saves their changes, the pdf file invoice is overwritten with a blank.

I am not sure how to solve this problem and retrieve the already saved pdf file invoice so that when the user saves their changes the pdf file invoice doesn't get overwritten with a blank.

This is what I have so far:

```
public void PopulateForm()
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
    WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader myReader = null;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_displayVsoftInvoice", con);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("VSoftInvoiceID", txtID.Text);
    myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        txtInvoiceNo.Text = (myReader["InvoiceNo"].ToString());
        ddlInvoiceType.SelectedValue = (myReader["EventTypeID"].ToString());
        txtDateSent.Text = (myReader["DateSent"].ToString());
        txtDatePaid.Text = (myReader["DatePaid"].ToString());
        string InvSent = (myReader["InvoiceSent"].ToString());
        string InvPaid = (myReader["InvoicePaid"].ToString());

        if (InvSent == "True")
        {
            cbxInvSent.Checked = true;
        }
        if (InvPaid == "True")
        {
            cbxInvPaid.Checked = true;
        }

    }
    con.Close();
}


protected void btnSaveInvoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string contentType = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
        using (Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream)
        {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
            {
                byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
                WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ConnectionString);
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_insertUpdateVsoftInvoice", con);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("VSoftInvoiceID", txtID.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CenterID", ddlCenter.SelectedItem.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("InvoiceTypeID", ddlInvoiceType.SelectedItem.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("InvoiceNo", txtInvoiceNo.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("InvoiceSent", this.cbxInvSent.Checked ? "1" : "0");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("InvoicePaid", this.cbxInvPaid.Checked ? "1" : "0");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateSent", txtDateSent.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DatePaid", txtDatePaid.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("InvoiceName", filename);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ContentType", contentType);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Data", bytes);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ModifiedBy", txtUser.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateModified", DateTime.Now);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                Response.Redirect("VsoftInvoice.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
```

Please advise me on how I can solve this problem so that my already saved pdf invoice doesn't get overwritten with a blank.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We need to clarify one of two things:
1- is that happening when editing without uploading a document?if yes then I think you need to save the file only when there is file uploaded (modifying your btnSaveInvoice_Click method)
2- if there is another edit method then please share the code
Good luck further.